# Testcafe- unable to launch long url with 4127 characters

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

We are sending a payload token in URL on redirect which is lengthy encrypted payload which is around 4127 characters and TestCafe is unable to process this url and seeing blank page

It works with small url only issue is with long url, please help on this issue

Comment: TestCafe uses the url rewriting mechanism which can slightly increase the url length. If you run your tests in Chrome, please try updating your TestCafe version to the latest one and run your tests with the `--native-automation` flag. It will allow you to avoid url rewriting. Please note that starting with version 3.0.0, Native Automation will be enabled by default.

Comment: We are sending encrypted payload(access token) in the url which of 4000 characters length, we updated our test cafe version to 2.6.1 and tried with --native-automation flag but still its not working and still seeing blank page. In the browser console we are seeing 500 error for tasks.js call and seeing the error as referrer policy unsafe url

Comment: Let's continue our discussion in the [github thread](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/7780) you created